# How does 非難される translate to English?

Tags: suffixes

> あんた学校中から非難されてるわよ。

Taken from a manga. I mean, I sort of understand, but it's hard to fit it in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this link](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%9D%9E%E9%9B%A3), looks like "accused".

V + される ([passive form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass), V is done to the subject)

Can translate it to something like "you're being accused throughout the school"